# R how to calculate the dip and dip direction of regression plane

Tags: r

I using regression in R to fit a plane to some 3D point data.  I would like to determine the dip and dip direction of the plane. Example data as follows:

```
require(scatterplot3d)

df <- iris[iris$Species == "setosa", 1:3]

s3d <- scatterplot3d(df[,1:3], asp = 1, type = "h", angle = 45,
                     box = FALSE, las = 1, pch = 16, cex.symbols = 2,
                     color  = "red")

# Create flat plane regression surface

Srf <- lm(df$Petal.Length ~ df$Sepal.Width + df$Sepal.Length)
s3d$plane3d(Srf,col = "blue")
```

I understand I should be able to determine the dip and dip direction from the normal of the plane 'Srf' (from the regression outputs) but could not find a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question [here](https://www.tjscientific.com/2017/08/16/computationally-calculating-strike-and-dip-from-3-points/#respond).  The solution was to fit the regression plane then define three points on the plane.  From the three points, two vectors could be defined in the plane of the regression surface.  The cross product of these two vectors is the normal vector to the regression plane and from this normal the dip and strike can be computed.  The following (albeit long example) uses some real data

```
# Data ... 48 points from test data
p1 <- c(518458.9470, 6479704.947, 1890.820847)
p2 <- c(518480.0626, 6479701.156, 1890.193591)
p3 <- c(518499.0065, 6479711.374, 1886.774569)
p4 <- c(518496.8636, 6479699.229, 1885.100577)
p5 <- c(518459.7483, 6479688.020, 1892.175793)
p6 <- c(518467.6447, 6479699.930, 1893.519824)
p7 <- c(518457.5226, 6479675.721, 1890.844966)
p8 <- c(518461.8681, 6479678.843, 1890.410706)
p9 <- c(518475.9205, 6479688.352, 1886.087544)
p10 <- c(518484.8952, 6479689.199, 1883.718843)
p11 <- c(518459.2030, 6479664.548, 1890.443068)
p12 <- c(518507.4322, 6479687.167, 1881.413087)
p13 <- c(518504.5215, 6479698.391, 1881.212976)
p14 <- c(518500.0602, 6479687.684, 1877.542193)
p15 <- c(518492.1190, 6479677.069, 1881.828390)
p16 <- c(518492.7505, 6479722.454, 1891.555791)
p17 <- c(518484.0805, 6479724.983, 1892.019543)
p18 <- c(518482.1924, 6479716.174, 1890.919477)
p19 <- c(518480.2579, 6479724.665, 1891.334378)
p20 <- c(518456.9439, 6479711.079, 1892.799963)
p21 <- c(518458.4682, 6479714.983, 1894.883456)
p22 <- c(518479.2151, 6479652.222, 1877.204210)
p23 <- c(518465.0516, 6479661.340, 1883.954998)
p24 <- c(518470.0939, 6479667.344, 1880.732197)
p25 <- c(518479.3615, 6479663.069, 1881.776801)
p26 <- c(518498.1744, 6479721.000, 1892.271407)
p27 <- c(518500.6880, 6479732.937, 1896.124964)
p28 <- c(518509.4069, 6479730.661, 1896.459655)
p29 <- c(518510.2077, 6479738.880, 1892.534405)
p30 <- c(518517.3703, 6479712.054, 1881.032976)
p31 <- c(518518.6171, 6479707.302, 1876.525206)
p32 <- c(518520.3469, 6479700.464, 1877.142107)
p33 <- c(518459.3177, 6479724.368, 1893.690051)
p34 <- c(518470.8911, 6479711.129, 1892.488857)
p35 <- c(518516.6978, 6479725.756, 1881.734010)
p36 <- c(518522.1993, 6479724.212, 1877.933734)
p37 <- c(518524.3916, 6479737.784, 1883.449039)
p38 <- c(518533.9092, 6479732.428, 1878.840653)
p39 <- c(518533.5349, 6479725.281, 1877.119517)
p40 <- c(518547.2435, 6479724.087, 1872.469104)
p41 <- c(518534.7529, 6479712.416, 1872.604159)
p42 <- c(518533.0184, 6479700.285, 1878.008852)
p43 <- c(518545.4573, 6479695.247, 1881.130858)
p44 <- c(518474.6323, 6479723.545, 1892.980152)
p45 <- c(518468.3802, 6479731.868, 1892.745709)
p46 <- c(518466.9959, 6479725.708, 1893.177289)
p47 <- c(518544.7851, 6479736.154, 1876.968941)
p48 <- c(518483.8061, 6479652.647, 1885.268907)

# Create data frame from the points
df <- data.frame(t(data.frame((mget(paste0("p",1:48))))))
names(df) <- c("x", "y", "z")

# Plot data and the name of each point
require(scatterplot3d)

s3d <- scatterplot3d(df[,1:3], asp = 1, type = "h", angle = 60,
                     box = FALSE, las = 1, pch = 16, cex.symbols = 3,
                     color  = "red")

text(s3d$xyz.convert(df[ ,1:3]), labels = row.names(df),col = "white")


# Create flat plane regression surface and add to the plot
Srf <- lm(df$z ~ df$x + df$y)
s3d$plane3d(Srf,col = "grey50",lty = 12, draw_polygon = TRUE, lwd = 2)

# Define three points on the regression plane 
# these are within the region of interest but could be anywhere
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
p1 <- c(518455.5, 6479739.5, x1 * Srf$coefficients[2]  + y1 * Srf$coefficients[3] + Srf$coefficients[1])
p2 <- c(518455.5, 6479640.5, x2 * Srf$coefficients[2]  + y2 * Srf$coefficients[3] + Srf$coefficients[1])
p3 <- c(518554.5, 6479739.5, x3 * Srf$coefficients[2]  + y3 * Srf$coefficients[3] + Srf$coefficients[1])

# Combine them into a data frame
pts <- data.frame(rbind(p1, p2, p3))
names(pts) <- c("x", "y", "z")

# Add the three points to the plot and label
s3d$points3d(pts[ ,1],pts[, 2],pts[, 3], col = c("forest green","blue","orange")
             , type = "h", pch = 16, cex = 3)


text(s3d$xyz.convert(pts[ ,1:3]), labels=row.names(pts),col = "white")

# Compute coordinates of pole to origin (0,0,0) ... see link reference for details
u1 = (y1 - y2)*(z3 - z2) - (y3 - y2) * (z1 - z2)
u2 = -((x1 - x2)*(z3 - z2) - (x3 - x2) * (z1 - z2))
u3 = (x1 - x2)*(y3 - y2) - (x3 - x2) * (y1-y2)


# Compute easting component using geological right hand rule
Est <- ifelse(u2 < 0, u2, -u2)

# Compute northing component using geological right hand rule
Nth <- ifelse(u3 >0, u1, -u1)

# Compute strike and dip~
Stk = acos(Nth/sqrt(Est^2 + Nth^2)) * (180/pi)
Dip = asin(sqrt(u1^2 + u2^2)/ sqrt(u1^2 + u2^2 + u3^2)) * (180/pi)
```